# Gradle: Overriding jar task for dependent project

Tags: gradle

I am newbie to gradle so please dont mind if the question is trivial.
I have a multi-project tree in gradle.
My logp-common project has following build script

```
configurations {
       protobuf
       compile.extendsFrom protobuf
}


version = '5.1'

defaultTasks = ['clean', 'jar']

dependencies {
    compile 'net.atomex.schema:rtb-proto:1.0.7-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:1.0:jdk15'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.6.1'
    compile 'nl.bitwalker:UserAgentUtils:1.6'
    compile 'org.apache.pig:pig:0.8.0'
    compile 'args4j:args4j:2.0.16'
       compile ('org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:0.20.2-cdh3u3') {
               exclude group:'com.cloudera.cdh', module:'hadoop-ant'
                exclude group:'javax.servlet', module:'jsp-api'
        }
    protobuf 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.4.1'

    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:15.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.8.2'
}

jar {
   from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
   manifest { attributes 'Main-Class': 'test.Main' }
}
```

And then there is userEventJob project which uses this(logp-common) project as dependency.

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':logp-common')
    compile 'args4j:args4j:2.0.16'
    compile 'junit:junit:4.8.1'
    compile project(':input-file-provider') 
    compile 'org.apache.hive:hive-exec:0.13.1'
    compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'

}


jar {
    version = '1.0'
        exclude('*.properties') 
        exclude('protobuf*.jar')
    from(project.configurations.runtime) {
        into 'lib'
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that in the logpcommon jar there are classes from protobuf jar include since logpcommon is a uber jar.
I cannot remove it since logpcommon jar is sometimes used individually then it should contain the protobuf jar class.
But i dont want protobuf classes if i invoke the logpcommon as a dependency from userEventJob.

Thanks.

Comment: You can produce two different jars in your logp project, one as a uberjar for standalone and one as a thin jar to be used as dependency in the second project. There isn't a straightforward way to add part of a jar as dependency to second project.

Comment: @RaGe : i added a second task which generates the required output when invoked independently. But how do I make it a part of build task , so that whenever i do a 'gradle clean build' it creates both the jars.??

Comment: Make the second task of `type:Jar`, then it is run when your build process runs the `Jar` task

Comment: Infact, I would say don't override the jar task like you're doing above, just create an additional fatjar task of type jar to create a jar with protobuf in it. Default jar will produce your thin jar